# Are there real-valued functions $f,g$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|>1$ for $x\ne y$?

Tags: calculus

Do there exist two functions $f,g:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$ which are not equal we have

$$\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert + \vert g(x)-g(y) \vert>1\;?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were such functions, we could define a map $F\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$, $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ such that the distance between $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ is $>\frac12\sqrt 2$ for $x\ne y$. That makes $F(\mathbb R)$ a discrete subset of $\mathbb R^2$, which is at most countable - contradiction.